# React Native: run javascript module from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to run javascript module twice a day in background, even if app is closed. I use BroadcastReceiver on Java side, but I don't know how to run javascript from onReceive() method without showing react View. I found one solution that run all application, but I'm looking for something like workers/service that will works in background.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String pn = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    Intent li = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pn);
    context.startActivity(li);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

React Native 0.36 introduced Headless JS as a way to run tasks in JavaScript while your app is in the background.

You should take a look at [this document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html).